# Как составить пакет для протокола Vanila Minecraft?

Tags: c++, minecraft

Всем привет! Я хочу написать бота для minecraft на языке C++, не используя для этого библиотек.
Я написал TCP клиент (WinSock2), могу подключиться к серверу, но как и что ему отправить не разобрался. Как выглядит готовое к отправке рукопожатие? Как разобраться в этом?
https://wiki.vg/Protocol.
Варианты использовать Python или либу не подходят, хочу принципиально сделать на С++

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: *"не используя для этого библиотек"* Начнем с того, что WinSock2 - это библиотека. *"Как выглядит готовое к отправке рукопожатие?"* Расскажите подробнее, в чем сложность? По ссылке есть описание структуры пакета handshake. В начале статьи есть объяснения, что значит каждый тип в этой структуре.

Comment: Я знаю что WinSock2 библиотека, я имел ввиду те либы которые предлагают готовую реализацию бота. Мне не понятен протокол, да там описана структура и типы данных, но как я понял нужно составить это все в пакет который состоит из байт. Ну и вот, как мне перевести все данные в готовый пакет? Хотя-бы понять как он выглядит. Извните, может я несу чушь, я новичок, но очень хотел бы разобраться хотя-бы как подключиться к серверу, чтобы хоть на время там появился игрок.

Comment: Пакет - это массив байт, который вы отдаете в winsock. Поля лежат в массиве подряд. Вот я открыл описание handshake, первое поле: "Protocol Version - VarInt - currently 756 in Minecraft 1.17.1" - т.е. нужно записать число 756 в виде "VarInt". В начале статьи есть описание, что такое VarInt, и главное - пример функции `writeVarInt`, которая создает VarInt из int-а. Переписываете ее на С++, даете ей число 756, складываете полученные байты в массив. Потом дописываете в массив оставшиеся поля и отправляете его.

Comment: Спасибо, понял что просто не внимательно прочёл документацию.